# North of Map to point north pole always : programatically ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview, apple-maps

The case is the replicate the north pole indicator into a button and perform the rotation.I know this can be done by rotating the map view entirely.Is there any other neat way where the annotation stays normal to the ipad orientation even after rotation

**EDIT**

as @AlexWain says

```
mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading
```

is an excellent solution ...but only possible **when the user location displayed on map while rotating it**

I need just to show a region and point the map towards north on the button click and sadly it is not the users current location,and is not in visible at that time

Comment: For your task you can only manually rotate the view, and apply the inverse roataion to all annotations (and the copyright label). Please, once you have,  post a soultion which works for the copyright label.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has introduced that feature:

```
 Use mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading
```

This turns the map in the direction you are looking or moving.
In that case north on the map matches the direction of north.

**Update:**
If the location is outside of the view, there is NO neat way to do it.
You have to rotate the view, and apply the inverse rotation to all elements which should not be rotated (e.g annotations, pins, copyright label)

Comment: Yes it will work only if the current location is visible in the view.It fails in other cases